# how can i set a custom font in aspx .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, fonts

I have downloaded a font that I kind of like.
How can I set it in aspx so that I may integrate it in my website ? thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in the article [How To Use Custom Fonts On Your Website With CSS](http://www.howtoplaza.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-on-your-website-with-css).